# In a canvas, is it better to have a single context or multiples?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i'm currently developing a js app.
I'm not a js expert so i'm asking for tips.

My question is:
Is it good practice (performance-wise as well) to draw in a canvas with an array of context or it is better to have a single context with all the drawing inside?

Case 1:

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    contextAr[i] = canvasAr.getContext('2d');
    contextAr[i].beginPath();
    contextAr[i].arc(canvasAr.width / 2, canvasAr.height / 2, ...
}
```

Case 2:

```
contextAr.beginPath();
contextAr.arc(...);
contextAr.moveTo(...);
contextAr.LineTo(...);
```

A simple example could be a circle divided in 4 quarters. Should i treat the draw with a single context or should i treat each pieces separately.
I think i'm not fully grasping the meaning of context though.
Is contextAr[i] = canvasAr.getContext('2d'); a redundant call?
I would not be surprise if contextAr[i] had identical elements.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It's rather pointless obtaining a 2D context several times from the same canvas element as the same context object will be returned.

[From the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-canvas-getcontext) (my emphasis) -

> **Return the same object as was returned the last time** the method was
>   invoked with this same first argument.

So the common and best practice is to obtain a single reference to a context per canvas element and use that successively.

Comment: Say i have two geometries, 1 triangle and 1 square. What if i want to change the css  "visibility" parameter? in that case i should have used 2 context and each of them should have been stored in a variable. Right?

Comment: You are probably confusing context with *element* as you would have to use two different canvas elements to control them separately using CSS. You can only have a single context per element (the context allows us to draw to the element it's bound to).

Comment: So in this case i would need 2 canvas each with only 1 context right?

Comment: @user217354 that's correct if you want to be able to control them separately using CSS (that is: one context per element). You could also use a single SVG for this using groups and style those groups using CSS (I know this is out of scope, but an alternative approach..). If the canvas drawings are found in the same area you could also build logic to toggle the different graphics, but it would require JavaScript to do so.